# how solve Android resource linking failed error?

Tags: android, xml

```
Android resource linking failed

C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\interfaceTP1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:33: AAPT: error: resource string/prompt_email (aka com.example.interfacetp1:string/prompt_email) not found.

C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\interfaceTP1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:48: AAPT: error: resource string/prompt_password (aka com.example.interfacetp1:string/prompt_password) not found.

C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\interfaceTP1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:48: AAPT: error: resource string/action_sign_in_short (aka com.example.interfacetp1:string/action_sign_in_short) not found.
```

I'm a beginner so all help will be very appreciated, 
I didn't understand how to solve the error , I have just started android

Comment: could you upload here your res/strings.xml file ?

Comment: you have to go to your strings.xml file and define these : `prompt_email, prompt_password,action_sign_in_short`

Comment: I compile by adding these variables in the file string.xml and the code was compiled without error but the app does not open on mobile it says "app stops systematically"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find how to incorporate the sources for the strings; you must be clear about the location of the Resources and then access them.
Resources are used for anything from defining colors, images, layouts, menus, and string values. The value of this is that nothing is hardcoded. Everything is described in these resource files and then can be referenced within your application's code. The simplest of these resources and the most common is using string resources to allow for flexible, localized text.

- The first step is to define the String Resource.
  I might add the string resource to res/values/strings.xml
- Referencing an App Resource.
  Now that we have defined our string resource, we can access that resource in either our Java code or our XML layouts at any time.

Resource reference:

- In Java: R.string.string_name
- In XML: @string/string_name
- In C#: Resources.String.string_name

For example in your case defined String.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="prompt_email">your_prompt_email</string>
        <string name="prompt_password">your_prompt_password</string>
        <string name="action_sign_in_short">your_action_sign_in_short</string>
    </resources>
```

Well, to use them from an activity:

- In java : getString(R.string.prompt_email);
- In XML: @string/prompt_email
- In C#: GetString(Resources.String.prompt_email);